# Configure Sublime Text 3 as git core.editor in Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, sublimetext3

I want to use Sublime Text as my editor for git in Cygwin (I think it's v. 2.6.1-1, but in any event, it's a recent version).

I set core.editor by doing

```
git config --global core.editor "/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe -n -w"
```

Now if I do

```
git commit --amend
```

git launches Sublime, but when I try to save the message, I get

```
Unable to save C:\home\david\my_git_clone\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? I've found lots of explanations of how to do similar things, but none specific to git, Cygwin, and Sublime.

Answer (score 2):

Need to make an intervening shell script. Unlike difftool, git doesn't run editor invocation through shell so you have to force it.

So:
~/bin/git-editor.sh :

```
`cygpath "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe"` `cygpath -w $1`
```

~/.gitconfig :

```
[core]
    editor = ~/bin/git-editor.sh
```

The script doesn't have to be exactly at ~/bin. Can be anywhere as log as you enter the correct path to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing path for `COMMIT_EDITMSG` to Sublime explicitly. Update project's `.git/config` as follows:

```
[core]
        editor = /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe `cygpath -w $PWD/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` -w
```

`cygpath -w $PWD/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` will resolve absolute path to `COMMIT_EDITMSG` and convert it to Windows path format (according to [cygpath documentation](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html)):

> The -u and -w options indicate whether you want a conversion to UNIX
>   (POSIX) format (-u) or to Windows format (-w).

Comment: Thanks. But I can't get this to work. I added this line to my existing [core] section (using a tab to indent it), and git status now gives me "fatal: bad config line 9 in file .git/config". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with Mykhailo's solution. I'm using Ubuntu on Windows, so I have to use "wslpath" which works just like cygpath to change the directory format. The only problem now is that it opens two files;one that works fine, and another whose path is still in Unix formatting. Works, but I find it annoying having to close every it everytime.

Here's what I added to the gitconfig:

```
[core]
    editor = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Sublime\\ Text\\ 3/subl.exe `wslpath.sh -w $PWD/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` -nw
```